# bulkWrite vs initialize(Un)orderedBulkOp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulk

what is the differences between those 2 methods, and which should I use?

1. what is the diff between: initializeUnorderedBulkOp and bulkWrite with ordered: false
2. what is the diff between: initializeOrderedBulkOp and default bulkWrite

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

The difference is mainly in the usage. [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#examples) takes in an array of operations and **executes it immediately**.

[`initializeOrderedBulkOp`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/Collection.html#initializeOrderedBulkOp) and [`initializeUnorderedBulkOp`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/Collection.html#initializeUnorderedBulkOp) return an instance which can be used to build queries gradually and execute it at last using the `execute` function.

---

Late to the party but I had a similar confusion so did some digging up.

The difference lies in the API implementation and usage.

- ### [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#examples)

  According to the API reference,

  > Perform a bulkWrite operation without a fluent API

  In this method, you directly pass in an array of "write operations" as the first argument. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#examples) for examples. I think by **fluent API**, they mean you don't exactly *separate* your `update` operations from your `insert` operations or `delete` operations. Every operation is in one array.

  One crucial point is **These operations are executed immediately**.

  As noted in the question, the execution is ordered by default but can be changed to unordered by setting `{ ordered: false }` in the second argument which is a set of options.

  The return value of the function is [`BulkWriteResult`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/BulkWriteResult.html) which contains information about the executed bulk operation.
- ### [`initializeOrderedBulkOp`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/Collection.html#initializeOrderedBulkOp) and [`initializeUnorderedBulkOp`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/Collection.html#initializeUnorderedBulkOp)

  Referring to the API reference again,

  > Initiate an In order bulk write operation

  As it says here, these methods **initialize/return an instance which provides an API for building block operations**. Those instances are of the class [`OrderedBulkOperation`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/OrderedBulkOperation.html) and [`UnorderedBulkOperation`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/UnorderedBulkOperation.html) respectively.

  ```js
  const bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  // `bulk` is of the type UnorderedBulkOperation
  ```

  This `bulk` variable provides a "fluent API" which allows you to *build* your queries across the application:

  ```js
  bulk.find( { /** foo **/ } ).update( { $set: { /** bar **/ } } );
  ```

  Bear in mind, these queries **are not executed** in the above code. You can keep on building the whole operation and when all the write operations are "called", we can finally execute the query:

  ```js
  bulk.execute();
  ```

  This `execute` function returns a [`BulkWriteResult`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/BulkWriteResult.html) instance which is basically what `bulkWrite` returns. Our database is finally changed.

### Which one should you use?

It depends on your requirements.

If you want to update a lot of documents with separate queries and values from an existing array, `bulkWrite` seems a good fit. If you want to build your bulk operation through a fairly complex business logic, the other options make sense. Note that you can achieve the same by constructing a global array gradually and passing it in the end to `bulkWrite`.